# ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback not called on app termination?

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

`ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` working case:

- Press home button going to background change in
  native contact book (add,remove,change), (open app)comes to foreground
  `ExternalChangeCallback` received.

`ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` not working case:

- Double click home button kill the App from the dock, change in native
  contact book `ExternalChangeCallback` not received on launching the
  application

Comment: The OS doesn't track whether your application was listening for notifications from a previous run. That's the expected behavior.

Comment: @smriti Yadav i am not receiving AbAddressbook ExternalChangeCallback after terminating my app . any help?

Comment: neither working case for me :(